# Matiyasevich polynomial proof

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, polynomials, prime-numbers

Can someone provide a proof, or a link to a proof, of why does the Matiyasevich polynomial always generate primes for the nonnegative results? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you read Matiyasevich's original paper? Or his book?

Comment: The book [Hilbert's Tenth Problem](http://www.amazon.com/Hilberts-10th-Problem-Foundations-Computing/dp/0262132958/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1349814465&sr=1-1&keywords=hilberts+tenth+problem) goes through all that rather well.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the right side, I´m going to investigate.